# HTML5 video performance testing tool

Tags: javascript, html, video

I need to test the performance of HTML5 Videos embedded in a web page under concurrent user load.

Video details:

Format :  MP4

Duration: 1 Min.

Video resolution: 1080p (1920 x 1080)

PlugIns:  No plugins used

Stream:   Progressive Download and recorded stream (not Live)

Browsers: HTML5 enabled browsers

Can anyone suggest tools for the below requirements.

1) A tool which is useful to develop automation scripts for recording HTML5 video requests and playback the video under load.

2) A monitoring tool to measure Real User experience of HTML5 video performance metrics (i.e buffering time, play time, lag length etc) under load.

Thanks,

Raghu

Comment: all the properties and the events you need are available on the <video> tag.

Comment: this isn't really a SO question (asking for recommendations vs solving a programming question) but there are a number of services (eg http://www.webpagetest.org/) who do load testing and for the analytics there are frameworks like https://github.com/Offbeatmammal/jsErrLog which you can adapt to report metrics against various browser events